# HandlebarsJS How to split a string

Tags: handlebars.js

I have to split up a string, which is delivered as JSON.

I have the following JSON output:

```
"title" : "Rihanna - Pon de replay"
```

And I need to display it like this

```
PON DE REPLAY
Rihanna
```

Right now my Handlebars template look like this:

```
<div>
  {{#each this}}
    <p>{{title}}</p>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Is there someone who could help me out? I would really appreciate it! Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will need to create an helper for this.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('splitTitle', function(title) {
  var t = title.split(" - ");
  return t[1] + " <br/> " + t[0];
});
```

and the tempalte should be like this,

```
<div>
  {{#each this}}
    <p>{{splitTitle title}}</p>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Edit: To render HTML output, use triple curly braces `{{{splitTitle title}}}`

```
<div>
  {{#each this}}
    <p>{{{splitTitle title}}}</p>
  {{/each}}
</div>
```

Comment: it would be better to use safe string if the helpers are returning an html like this :- new Handlebars.SafeString(t[1] + " <br/> " + t[0]);

Comment: This is great thanks! Is it possible to check for more special characters? like adding if conditions? for example for commas, dots etc?